# multiple parameter to Url.Action does not generate proper routing path even after defining routes in Asp.net Mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have following code

```
 @(Url.Action("Files","Folder", new RouteValueDictionary(new {fileGroup = group,fileName= name, ticket = nodeId})))
```

I have routes defined

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "FolderFiles",
            url: "Folder/Files/{fileGroup}/{fileName}/{ticket}/{path}",
            defaults:
                new
                {
                    controller = "Folder",
                    action = "Files",
                    fileGroup = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    fileName = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    ticket= UrlParameter.Optional,
                    path = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

which generates

```
http://mydomain.com/Folder/Files?fileGroup=Temp&fileName=Test2&ticket=461c9a67aa94
```

but i want following url generated

```
http://mydomain.com/Folder/Files/Temp/Test2/461c9a67aa94/
```

is it possible to get the above desired url formation?

thanks.

Comment: Do you by any chance have other routes defined before that one? Like maybe the default MVC route `{controller}/{action}/{id}`?

Comment: nope, my route is defined above the default one so i dont see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the default route should be handled first.

Try to put your route definition after the default one.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "FolderFiles",
        url: "Folder/Files/{fileGroup}/{fileName}/{ticket}/{path}",
        defaults:
            new
            {
                controller = "Folder",
                action = "Files",
                fileGroup = UrlParameter.Optional,
                fileName = UrlParameter.Optional,
                ticket = UrlParameter.Optional,
                path = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

To link your action :

```
@Html.ActionLink("My link", "Files", "Folder", new {fileGroup ="Group1", fileName = "file1", ticket = "ticke1", path ="path1"}, null)
```

Or execute it :

```
@(Html.Action("Files","Folder", new {fileGroup = "Group1",fileName= "file1", ticket = "ticke1", path ="path1"}))
```